# NSString Decoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsstringencoding

I have a situation, I don't know what causing it.

I have got a string from server like this

```
NSString *str=@"\\u3060\\u3044\\u3053\\u3093\\u3001\\u5927\\u6839\\n";
```

I am trying to decode it using the following code..

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self decodeString:str]);


-(NSString*)decodeString:(NSString *)inputString{
    NSData *utfStringData=[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *output=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:utfStringData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    return output;
}
```

I get **nil** as output.

But when I remove extra "\" from the input string, NSString itself shows the proper wording without even passing into decodeString function, see below

[image]

So I decided the replace the extra "\" from input string using following code

```
inputString=[inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
```

Above code doesn't work either.

My question is -> What am I doing wrong? How does it work?

Thanks for Helping.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a UTF8 string to ASCII?

Comment: Your string is UTF-16 encoded, not UTF-8

Comment: you want  try to clean \\ from dictionary data and store data into string

Comment: @RB1509 How to do that?

Comment: Your `decodeString:` method won't work. You already have a valid string, then you're getting the UTF8 representation of it and then trying to interpret it in a different encoding.

Comment: @mag_zbc is there a way to determine encoding type for incoming string? I will try it with UTF16.

Comment: _is there a way to determine encoding type for incoming string?_ - you're not supposed to determine encoding of incoming string, that information should be provided in your web service's documentation

Comment: @mag_zbc Yes the api is returning UTF8 string the problem is the decoding works for some strings but doesn’t with some, so I thought there is definitely a difference somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CFStringTransform` to convert unescape unicode characters. `CFStringTransform` can perform real magic like transliterations between greek and latin (or about any known scripts), but it can also be used to do mundane tasks like unescaping strings from a server:

```
NSString *str=@"\\u3060\\u3044\\u3053\\u3093\\u3001\\u5927\\u6839\\n";
NSString *convertedString = [str mutableCopy];

CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);
NSLog(@"convertedString: %@", convertedString);     //convertedString: だいこん、大根\n
```

`CFStringTransform` is really powerful. It supports a number of predefined transforms, like case mappings, normalizations or unicode character name conversion. You can even design your own transformations.

OS X 10.11 and iOS 9 add the following method to Foundation:

```
- (nullable NSString *)stringByApplyingTransform:(NSString *)transform reverse:(BOOL)reverse;
```

Here is the code with the above method:

```
NSString *convertedString = [str stringByApplyingTransform:@"Any-Hex/Java" reverse:YES];
NSLog(@"convertedString: %@", convertedString);     //convertedString: だいこん、大根\n
```

Comment: Brilliant!! If you could add some explanation what is happening, this solution looks similar to android *StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava* function..

Comment: Making transform=YES/NO determines either to `unescape/escape`, right?

Comment: The last parameter is boolean that, if true, specifies that the inverse transform should be used (if it exists).

Comment: Hi, any idea why newline "\n" doesn't show a newline when I supply the convertedString to `UITextView` ?

Comment: Hello, after the conversion, it applies another backslash before `\n` so just use `convertedString = [convertedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];` before suppling the `convertedString` into `UITextView`

Comment: Yes thanks, it is working, I didn't realize that it added extra backslash.